# Download zip file as response after hitting Post Call in Rest assured

Tags: java, post, rest-assured, zip

I am trying [this download link in swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLQA0.png) from post call in java using RestAssured. But after hitting the endpoint, the response is some unwanted characters displayed on console. This is a zip file we are talking about. How can i download the file and save it in my local?

Answer (score 0):

Save file from response:

```
Path pathToFile = new File("path/to/your/file").toPath();
Files.copy(response.asInputStream(), pathToFile);
```